# Memory allocation error in Android App after using external library

Tags: android, parse-platform, runtime-error

I added parse library for social integration to my android app, and the app is crashing when it is run on emulator. An error saying trouble with memory allocation is shown. Following is the logcat. 
Can someone please point me to the direction of solving it? Thanks

```
04-19 12:12:59.973    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.749ms total 65.803ms 
04-19 12:12:59.973    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 651344 free bytes and 636KB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 4096 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 0 bytes)" (recursive case) 
04-19 12:12:59.976    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable 
04-19 12:12:59.976    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x735b3970 self=0xb4606800 
04-19 12:12:59.976    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ | sysTid=2366 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb7790160 
04-19 12:12:59.976    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=120 stm=19 core=0 HZ=100 
04-19 12:12:59.976    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ | stack=0xbf4cc000-0xbf4ce000 stackSize=8MB 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #00 pc 00005ac3  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+83) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #01 pc 00002e91  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+33) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #02 pc 003c3f3a  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+138) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #03 pc 0038d03c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+268) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #04 pc 0039142b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+459) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #05 pc 001ec6fb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #06 pc 001f030d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2749) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #07 pc 00176b91  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::AllocObject(art::Thread*)+1329) 
04-19 12:12:59.977    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #08 pc 003905de  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowNewWrappedException(art::ThrowLocation const&, char const*, char const*)+830) 
04-19 12:12:59.983    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #09 pc 003914d2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+626) 
04-19 12:12:59.983    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #10 pc 001ec6fb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243) 
04-19 12:12:59.983    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #11 pc 001f030d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2749) 
04-19 12:12:59.983    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #12 pc 00176b91  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::AllocObject(art::Thread*)+1329) 
04-19 12:12:59.983    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #13 pc 0031a6b8  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::Alloc(art::Thread*, int)+872) 
04-19 12:12:59.983    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #14 pc 0031b0fc  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::AllocFromModifiedUtf8(art::Thread*, char const*)+44) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #15 pc 0038fc83  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::InternalStackTraceToStackTraceElementArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, int*)+1027) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #16 pc 00340650  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Throwable_nativeGetStackTrace(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*)+80) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ native: #17 pc 00000fe6  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Throwable_nativeGetStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Object_2+142) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.nativeGetStackTrace!(Native method) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.getInternalStackTrace(Throwable.java:264) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:318) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:335) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690) 
04-19 12:12:59.984    2366-2366/com.eclecticderivatives.easyquiz E/art﹕ [ 04-19 12:12:59.998  2366: 2366 I/art      ]
Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.861ms total 13.312ms
```

Comment: The problem may be caused elsewhere from where it is appearing.  For example, do you have a lot of bitmaps loaded, or a few large ones?   There are powerful tools in the DDMS panel you can use to examine your allocations and understand the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools that can be used to debug OOM - see [Investigating Your RAM Usage](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html). Try to get HPROF dump - perhaps you or the library you are using are not releasing some objects.